# Solve no longer working

Tags: equation-solving

I have defined four functions

```
fA[x_,y_]:=Sqrt[x^2+(y+2)^2]
fAB[x_,y_]:=Sqrt[(x-3)^2+(y+1)^2]*Boole[(y>=(1/2-(1/2)*x))]+(Sqrt[5]+Sqrt[(x-1)^2+(y)^2])*Boole[(y<(1/2-(1/2)*x))]
fABC[x_,y_]:=Sqrt[(x-3)^2+(y-3)^2]*Boole[(y>=x)]+(2*Sqrt[2]+Sqrt[(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2])*Boole[(y<x)]
fABCD[x_,y_]:=Sqrt[(x+2)^2+(y-4)^2]*Boole[(y<=(1-(3/2)*x))]+(Sqrt[13]+Sqrt[(x)^2+(y-1)^2])*Boole[(y>(1-(3/2)*x))]
```

Before defining the fourth one, I used Solve and it worked as expected.
However after defining the fourth one, Solve ceased to work, even for functions that it previously did work for.

```
Solve[fA[x,y]==fABC[x,y],y]
```

Now gives the error "Solve: Undefined is not a valid variable.", and returns

`Solve[Undefined,Undefined]`

The problem seems to have something to do with variable `y`, as Solve still works fine with other variables.

Does anyone know what could have gone wrong? Sorry if an equivalent question has already been asked. I couldn't find one.

Comment: it works ok in V 12.1 screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yp6IG.png)  which version are you using? Can you start from clean kernel and post an image same as above?

Comment: In version 10.1 I get the same output with three or four definitions: `{{y -> ConditionalExpression[1/5 (7 - 3 x), x < 7/8]}, {y -> ConditionalExpression[1 - 3 x + 2 Sqrt[2 - 4 x + 4 x^2], x > 7/8]}}`

Comment: Works for me as well; I get the same output as Nasser (on v. 12.0 for Mac).  Sorry for giving such an obvious comment, but did you try quitting the kernel?